# Conditionally return records based on combination of field values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am new to this forum and sql and was hoping that someone would be able to help me.

I am trying to create a query that will return records that have equal values in all of the fields except one.

I have the following fields in the table:

Part number|Year|Make|Model

I want to return all records that are available in one year (2011), but not available in another (2012).  For example:

Part number|Year|Make|Model
123456|2011|Ford|Focus

This record would return, because there is no 123456|2012|Ford|Focus combination.

However, I don't want any of the records returned if there is a record for the 2012.

Part number|Year|Make|Model
123456|2011|Ford|Focus
123456|2012|Ford|Focus

No records should return if this condition exists.

I hope that I explained that well.  Please let me know if I need to clarify any points.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**:

Does this look right?

```
SELECT *
FROM [mytable].[dbo].[apps] yt
    WHERE yt.make in (47,54, 48, 59, 3, 42, 21, 67, 1168, 76, 40, 39)
    and yt.model in (432, 2484, 16206, 2487, 6831, 5858, 659, 663, 2816, 688, 668, 670, 6089, 2427, 752, 21, 349, 356, 108, 883, 2440, 16227, 1011, 303, 6867, 110, 440, 975, 286, 287)
    and yt.Year = 2011
        AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                           FROM [mytable].[dbo].[apps] yt2
                           WHERE yt.part# = yt2.part#
                               AND yt.make = yt2.make
                               AND yt.model = yt2.model
                               AND yt2.Year = 2012)
order by part#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT yt.PartNumber, yt.Year, yt.Make, yt.Model
    FROM YourTable yt
    WHERE yt.Year = 2011
        AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                           FROM YourTable yt2
                           WHERE yt.PartNumber = yt2.PartNumber
                               AND yt.Make = yt2.Make
                               AND yt.Model = yt2.Model
                               AND yt2.Year = 2012)
```

Comment: @BinaryWorrier I didn't see that requirement in the question.

Comment: Well I guess, but you're just putting the problem off for a year until there are three years of data :)

Comment: All of the records are in the same table.  Will this alter the query?

Comment: @user955289: This query only references one table. For lack of a better name, I chose to call it `YourTable`. That one table is referenced with two different aliases (`yt` and `yt2`) but it's the same table.

Comment: Hi Joe-  Thanks for the help.  I added the adjusted query to my original post.  Does that look right?

Comment: @user955289 Looks OK. Assuming Models are subsets of Makes, the `yt.make in (47,54, 48, 59, 3, 42, 21, 67, 1168, 76, 40, 39)` portion of your query may be redundant since you're also searching for specific models.

Comment: I ran it with just one make/model combination and it worked perfectly.  I do have one more question.  The model IDs may be associated with multiple make IDs, and that is why I specified certain IDs.  What I really need is that combination of those two fields.  For example, model code 2484 may be associated with make code 47 and 67.  I only want the records where it is associated with 47.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I figured that last bit out.  Thanks for all of your help Joe!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT c.PartNumber, c.Year, c.Make, c.Model
FROM Cars c
inner join 
(
    SELECT count(*) [count], PartNumber, Make, Model
    from cars
    GROUP BY PartNumber, Make, Model
    HAVING count(*) = 1
) as g 
ON c.PartNumber = g.PartNumber and c.Make = g.Make and c.Model = g.Model
```

With this setup code

```
create table Cars
(partnumber nvarchar(20), [year] int, make nvarchar(20), model nvarchar(20))

insert into Cars
select '123456', 2010, 'Ford', 'Focus'
union
select '123456', 2011, 'Ford', 'Focus'
union
select '654321', 2010, 'Opel', 'Astra'
```

returns

```
PartNumber    Year    Make    Model
654321        2010    Opel    Astra
```

Comment: Sorry, sql wouldn't run, have fixed it up

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT t.PartNumber, t.Yr, t.Make, t.Model, t2.yr
FROM cars t left outer join cars t2 on 
    t.PartNumber = t2.PartNumber
    AND t.Make = t2.Make
    AND t.Model = t2.Model
    and t.yr <> t2.yr 
WHERE t.Yr = 2011   AND (t2.yr <> 2012 or t2.Yr  is null)
```

should handle

```
   part   make  model   yr 
   123456 Ford  Focus   2012 
   123456 Ford  Focus   2011 
   654321 Opel  Astra   2011 
   987654 Dodge Charger 2010 
   987654 Dodge Charger 2011
```

returning

```
part    yr      make    model   t2.yr
654321  2011    Opel    Astra   NULL
987654  2011    Dodge   Charger 2010
```

Comment: All of the records are in the same table.  Will this alter the query?